# How to write this kind of SQL in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to update a column `col` in table `tab`,whose data is like follows(comma separated, with the heading comma):

```
,test,oh,whatever,....,
```

Which can be too long to display,how can I update the column so that only the first `10` words are left?

Comment: Fix your schema first. Don't store comma separated values in database.
Read about normalization.

Comment: @Naktibalda you don't know whether these values can/have to be normalized. They could be arbitrary strings.

Comment: @Pekka: if they were just strings there would be no requirement treat them as individual words. I agree with @Naktibalda i.e. this is a violation of first normal form (1NF) which required scalar data types. Consider that this NFNF design has resulted in a question on SO because the SQL language lacks operators required to work with multi-valued data because it assumes all data types are scalar. Use the correct tool for the job ;)

Comment: @onedaywhen, the requirement to treat them as individual words might be indicative of violation of first normal form (even strongly indicative), but it does not strictly imply it. Semantics determine normal forms; and in this case truncating data suggest that the choice to consider it 'just a string' is semantically correct for the problem space which is modeled (of which we know very little about). In another words, yes, wamp should check the NF and *no* it does not necessarily means that it is NFNF.

Comment: @Unreason: you are indeed correct: I cannot be absolutely sure but I do strongly suspect. Sorry to use such strong terms, I find it fits best with the general style of comments on SO ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [substring_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
UPDATE table
SET column = SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, ',', 11)
```

(do check your UPDATES with SELECT before running them)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but I would recommend to do stuff like this on application level, not in the database.

You are not saying what language you are using. In PHP, this would be a job for the [`wordwrap`](http://www.php.net/wordwrap) function. It is able to intelligently chop off strings at the right position.

Alternatively, is storing the full string in the database, and doing the cutting at output time, not an option as well?

Comment: No,it's for developing environment, the data is messed up.